# get categories which are not linked to a static block

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I have a script to display all categories

```
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');

foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getName() == $current_cat) {
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a>\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($subcat).'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
}
```

But some of the categories are linked to a static block so i want to filter it out, anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I guess you know how to join tables and get data form there. Rest i am telling you here.**

If you do inspect element then you can see the name of that attribute for CMS Block is `landing page.` Now go to `eav_attribute` table and find that attribute there. In my case the **id is 50 (Most probably for you too.)**. Now go to `catalog_category_entity_int` table and check which `entity_id(category id)` has `value` for `attribute_id = 50`. Rest category ids value will be NULL.

[image: check the image here.]

Hope you get the whole idea. Enjoy !!